# How to resolve configurable issue with Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

In my understanding, if configurable setted to false, the property descriptor cannot be changed (re-define not allowed).

But when I test in chrome, node, firefox, safari, I get same results:

```
o = {}
Object.defineProperty(o, 't', {writable: true, configurable: false})
Object.defineProperty(o, 't', {writable: false, configurable: false}) // descriptor changes without error
Object.defineProperty(o, 't', {writable: true, configurable: false})
// this time I got expected error -  TypeError: Attempting to change writable attribute of unconfigurable property.
```

It seems like when writable is true, even configurable is false, we still could change the property descriptor.

Or, change a descriptor to false is always allowed?

What is the right behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `configurable` does [is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description):

> true if and only if **the type** of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.

And see:

> Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data descriptors and accessor descriptors. A data descriptor is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An accessor descriptor is a property described by a getter-setter pair of functions. A descriptor must be one of these two flavors; it cannot be both.

The **type** of a property descriptor refers to whether the descriptor is a data descriptor (one for which a value is meaningful) or an accessor descriptor (with a getter/setter). A non-configurable property cannot be changed from a data type to a getter/setter type, or vice versa.

```js
const o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 't', {writable: true, configurable: false})
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 't'));
Object.defineProperty(o, 't', { get() { }})
```

If you pass a `writable` key, the descriptor type defaults to a data descriptor, whose value is `undefined` if no `value` is passed.

The error you're seeing at the end is different. While you can change a writable non-configurable data descriptor to a non-writable data descriptor, you can't go the other way around - a non-writable, non-configurable data descriptor cannot be converted to a writable data descriptor. (See step 7 of [ValidateAndApplyPropertyDescriptor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor))

Comment: CertainPerformance, that is a nice explaination. I just want to add that Object.defineProperty() method is not commonly used method in general. but if we want to make a property of object to not to be deleted from object properties then configurable can help

Comment: so a getter/setter property is always allowed to change its getter/setter methods, even if configurable is false?

Comment: @portrayer No, non-configurable accessor descriptors can't be changed at all - see step 8 of the same section in the specification https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor It's just that non-configurable data descriptors can have their `writable` changed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think this behavior is not intuitive but you are right. Thank you so much.